# Output PHP into a Chart.js Graph

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to make it so that the labels and data from my database are printing to my chart.js chart. Right now I have fake data as a place holder. I was having issues making a Json_encode command so it would print the data. I need help figuring out the code so I could print the data into the graph, and print the labels.

Here is the code I tried already:

```
<html>
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$sentiment = new \PHPInsight\Sentiment();

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'sample', 'sample', 'workwership_data');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$jan01sql = "SELECT value FROM comments WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1530940734 AND 1531439758;";
$jan01result = mysqli_query($conn, $jan01sql);

while ($jan01row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($jan01result))
    {
    $jan01strings[] = $jan01row['value'];
}
$jan01 = implode("", $jan01strings);

$feb02sql = "SELECT value FROM comments WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1530940734 AND 1531439758;";
$feb02result = mysqli_query($conn, $feb02sql);

while ($feb02row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($feb02result))
{
    $feb02strings[] = $feb02row['value'];
}
$feb02 = implode("", $feb02strings);

$mar03sql = "SELECT value FROM comments WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1530940734 AND 1531439758;";
$mar03result = mysqli_query($conn, $mar03sql);

while ($mar03row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mar03result))
{
    $mar03strings[] = $mar03row['value'];
}
$mar03 = implode("", $mar03strings);

$apr04sql = "SELECT value FROM comments WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1530940734 AND 1531439758;";
$apr04result = mysqli_query($conn, $apr04sql);

while ($apr04row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($apr04result))
{
    $apr04strings[] = $apr04row['value'];
}
$apr04 = implode("", $apr04strings);

$may05sql = "SELECT value FROM comments WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1530940734 AND 1531439758;";
$may05result = mysqli_query($conn, $may05sql);

while ($may05row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($may05result))
{
    $may05strings[] = $may05row['value'];
}
$may05 = implode("", $may05strings);

$jun06sql = "SELECT value FROM comments WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1530940734 AND 1531439758;";
$jun06result = mysqli_query($conn, $jun06sql);

while ($jun06row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($jun06result))
{
    $jun06strings[] = $jun06row['value'];
}
$jun06 = implode("", $jun06strings);

$july07sql = "SELECT value FROM comments WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1530940734 AND 1531439758;";
$july07result = mysqli_query($conn, $july07sql);

while ($july07row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($july07result))
{
    $july07strings[] = $july07row['value'];
}
$july07 = implode("", $july07strings);

$strings= [];

array_push($strings, $jan01);
array_push($strings, $feb02);
array_push($strings, $mar03);
array_push($strings, $apr04);
array_push($strings, $may05);
array_push($strings, $jun06);
array_push($strings, $july07);

if (PHP_SAPI != 'cli') {
   echo "<pre>";
}

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $scores = $sentiment->score($string);
    $class = $sentiment->categorise($string);

    $positive[]=$scores['pos'];
    $negative[]=$scores['neg'];
    $neutral[]=$scores['neu'];
}

$dataPoints = array();

?>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="alldata.js">ALL</button>
<div id="chart1">
    <canvas id="linechart" position="relative" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
var example = document.getElementById("linechart");

var linechart = new Chart(example, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: ['9/21/18','9/22/18','9/23/18','9/24/18','9/25/18'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Month',
        data: [0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4,-0.9],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        lineTension: 0,
        fill: false
    },{
        label: 'Day',
        data: [0.1, 0.5, -0.5, 0.2,0.3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,0,255,1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        lineTension: 0,
        fill: false
    },{
        label: 'All',
        data: [0.2,0.2,-0.2, 0.4,-0.1],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,0,255,1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        lineTension: 0,
        fill: false,
        display: false
    }],
    },

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to research the DRY principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: Also, I don't see anywhere in your JS code that you're trying to output anything from PHP.

Comment: That's the primary issue i was having. i was going to put a Jason encode command in the data part of the js, but it kept spitting out errors. and i had some confusion of which variable i should use to out put the data.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Show us the errors. We don't know what you want your data to look like, but we can help with concrete problems.

Comment: I just added in <?php json_encode($strings) ?> to my js chart and now my graph is blank

Comment: data: {
        labels: [<?php json_encode($strings) ?>],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Month',
            data: [<?php json_encode($strings) ?>],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'

Comment: Ok, does the output look like data that the chart can use?

Comment: Basically it should be outputting the sentiment analysis from the data in my database. i did the sentiment analysis and it does work when i don't use the graph, but when i try to link it up, it just went blank.